# assigning setter / getter for js object

Tags: javascript, setter

I tried to assign a setter for my js "class":

```
function testing(){
    this.value = "content";
    set a(b){
        this.value = b;
    };
}
var test1 = new testing();
test1.a = "nope";
```

But it throws out `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` on line `set a(b){` could some one tell me how the correct syntax is ?

Comment: try using `Object.defineProperty`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

#### Constructor function and `Object.defineProperty`

To do it within a constructor function like you have, you'd use `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties`. For instance:

```
function Testing(){
    this.value = "content";
    Object.defineProperty(this, "a", {
        set: function(b){
            this.value = b;
        }
    });
}
```

**Live Example**:

```js
function Testing() {
  this.value = "content";
  Object.defineProperty(this, "a", {
    set: function(b) {
      this.value = b;
    }
  });
}
var t = new Testing();
snippet.log("t.value before: " + t.value);
t.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t.value after: " + t.value);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

*(Note: I made the first `t` in `Testing` capital because that's the **overwhelming** convention in JavaScript for constructor functions.)*

#### Constructor property and `Object.defineProperty` using prototype

Or you might define the setter on the prototype:

```
function Testing(){
    this.value = "content";
}
Object.defineProperty(Testing.prototype, "a", {
    set: function(b){
        this.value = b;
    }
});
```

**Live Example**:

```js
function Testing(){
    this.value = "content";
}
Object.defineProperty(Testing.prototype, "a", {
    set: function(b){
        this.value = b;
    }
});
var t1 = new Testing();
snippet.log("t1.value before: " + t1.value);
t1.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t1.value after: " + t1.value);
var t2 = new Testing();
snippet.log("t2.value before: " + t2.value);
t2.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t2.value after: " + t2.value);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### Constructor function and an object initializer for the prototype

The syntax you were trying to use is for object initializers, not constructor functions. We can use an object initializer to *replace* the `Testing.prototype`, like this:

```
function Testing(){
    this.value = "content";
}
Testing.prototype = {
    constructor: Testing, // The old object had this, so let's maintain it
    set a(b){
        this.value = b;
    }
};
```

**Live Example**:

```js
function Testing(){
    this.value = "content";
}
Testing.prototype = {
    constructor: Testing, // The old object had this, so let's maintain it
    set a(b){
        this.value = b;
    }
};
var t1 = new Testing();
snippet.log("t1.value before: " + t1.value);
t1.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t1.value after: " + t1.value);
var t2 = new Testing();
snippet.log("t2.value before: " + t2.value);
t2.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t2.value after: " + t2.value);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### An object initializer for a one-off object

This just creates a one-off object, not a function that you can use to build a bunch of these objects:

```
var t = {
  value: "content",
  set a(b) {
    this.value = b;
  }
};
```

**Live Example**:

```js
var t = {
  value: "content",
  set a(b) {
    this.value = b;
  }
};
snippet.log("t.value before: " + t.value);
t.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t.value after: " + t.value);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### A builder function and `Object.create` for the prototype

Constructor functions (functions you use with `new`) are not the only game in town for creating objects with prototypes behind them. You can do that with a builder function as well if you like, via `Object.create`:

```
var testingPrototype = {
    set a(b){
        this.value = b;
    }
};
function testing(){
    var obj = Object.create(testingPrototype);
    obj.value = "content";
    return obj;
}
```

You don't use `new` with these, because they create the object themselves:

**Live Example**:

```js
var testingPrototype = {
    set a(b){
        this.value = b;
    }
};
function testing(){
    var obj = Object.create(testingPrototype);
    obj.value = "content";
    return obj;
}
var t1 = testing();
snippet.log("t1.value before: " + t1.value);
t1.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t1.value after: " + t1.value);
var t2 = testing();
snippet.log("t2.value before: " + t2.value);
t2.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t2.value after: " + t2.value);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### A builder function, no prototype

Last but not least, you can use a builder function and not use a prototype:

```
function testing() {
    return {
        value: "content",
        set a(b){
            this.value = b;
        }
    };
}
```

You don't use `new` with these either:

**Live Example**:

```js
function testing(){
    return {
        value: "content",
        set a(b){
            this.value = b;
        }
    };
}
var t1 = testing();
snippet.log("t1.value before: " + t1.value);
t1.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t1.value after: " + t1.value);
var t2 = testing();
snippet.log("t2.value before: " + t2.value);
t2.a = "new content";
snippet.log("t2.value after: " + t2.value);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your and @garryp response ! It worked, both of them, but witch one is the better way ?

Comment: @Feirell: Neither is better. Both constructor functions and builder functions (the name for what garryp showed you) are perfectly valid ways to use JavaScript. Note that you don't use `new` with builder functions like garryp's (he seems unwilling to correct his answer; I gave up on it). One slight disadvantage to the approach in garryp's answer is that you can't assign the object a *prototype* (an object underlying your objects that has common functionality), which is frequently handy. You can do that with constructor functions or with `Object.create`, but not with the pattern he's shown.

Comment: @Feirell: I've added a fourth example (in the third position) above. Enjoy. :-)

Comment: Corwder ok, to be honest I am not sure what you meant, you wrote in the comment section of his answer that it is now not any more okay to use the `new` key word, but why ? And when I would use your object defining pattern how could I create multiple object out of that "class" ?

Comment: @Feirell: Right, the correct way to use garryp's pattern is just `var test1 = testing();` (without `new`). My last example is for making a one-off object. If you want to create a bunch of these (e.g., a "class" of them), then you'd want any of my first three examples (if you want to use constructor functions and `new`) or the new fifth example I'll add in a moment. :-)

Comment: You are amazing, I am so thankful for you effort. If I am reminding correctly you helped me with some of the other questions I had in the past, and every time you make your self so much trouble, this is in my opinion not something normal to do, so I would like to say thank you !
A little question why do I have to use `Object` in front of the `.defineProperty` ? And would there be a problem if I am using this notation style like you used in the first example ? Like is it a bad or uncommon style ?

Comment: @Feirell: It's a pleasure. I added fifth and sixth option above; the sixths is what gerryp showed you, but I figured I should be complete. JavaScript gives you lots of choice. :-) Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

In an example like this set needs to be part of an object:

One way of doing it is like this:

```
function testing(){
    var value = "content";
    return {
        set a(b){
            value = b;
        },
        get a() {
            return value;
        }
    };
}
var test1 = new testing();
test1.a = "nope";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/1s7v0rdn/

Comment: There's no point in using `new` with a non-constructor function.

Comment: The `new` was from the OP.

Comment: Yes, but the OP's function was a constructor function. Yours isn't.

Comment: Yes, but the OP's original question was about getters and setters ;-)

Comment: @garryp I am thankfull of any help, so yeah it is a bit out of scope but I am grateful for this :)